# setValue in range if nothing in an other range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Spreadsheet, I use *script editor* to insert an Xpath in one column between D2:D5.

```
function untitle() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('D2:D5');
  var cell = '=IMPORTXML(C2, "/html/body/div[2]")'; 
  range.setValue(cell);
};
```

C2 include the address of the website.

I would like to make the same think between E2:E5 **if there is nothing** in the cell D2:D5

How can I do?

EDIT I:

I use the code with xpath to get information in D2:D5

If the code get #N/A (or nothing) I use a second xpath in E2:E5

To be more lite, I would like to use the second xpath only if I get nothing in D row.

Now, So I use the code below but it check everything so it's not good.

```
function untitle() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('D2:D5');
  var range2 = sheet.getRange('E2:E5');
  var cell = '=IMPORTXML(C2, "/html/body/div[2]")'; 
  var cell2 = '=IMPORTXML(C2, "/html/body/div[3]")';
  range.setValue(cell);
  range2.setValue(cell2);
};
```

I would like to use two functions.

- The first, to get information in D2:D5
- The second, to get information in E2:E5 if the result is nothing (#N/A) in D2:D5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If the cells of "D2:D5" have values and/or formulas, you want to put the formula to "D2:D5".
- If the cells of "D2:D5" have no values and/or formulas, you want to put the formula to "E2:E5".

If my understanding for your question is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Flow:

The flow of modified script is as follows.

1. Retrieve values and formulas from the cells "D2:D5".
2. If there are the values or formulas in the cells, put the formulas to "D2:D5".
3. If there are no values or formulas in the cells, put the formulas to "E2:E5" using `offset()`.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
range.setValue(cell);
```

To:

```
var values = range.getValues().some(function(e) {return e[0]});
var formulas = range.getFormulas().some(function(e) {return e[0]});
if (values || formulas) {
  range.setValue(cell);
} else {
  range.offset(0, 1).setValue(cell);
}
```

#### Note:

- If you want to put the formula to "E2:E5" when there are only formulas in the "D2:D5", please remove `formulas` from the script.

#### References:

- [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset-columnoffset)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

### Added:

1. Put the formula of `cell` to "D2:D5".
2. Retrieve the results of the formulas.
3. Put the formula of `cell2` to "E2:E5" from the retrieved results.

   - `var cell2 = '=IMPORTXML(C2, "/html/body/div[3]")';`
   - In this case, when the results of "D2:D5" are `"#N/A"` or `""`, put the formula of `cell2`.

If my understanding for what you want is correct, how about this modified script? This script reflect above flow.

#### Modified script:

```
function untitle() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('D2:D5');
  var range2 = sheet.getRange('E2:E5');
  var cell = '=IMPORTXML(C2, "/html/body/div[2]")';
  range.setFormula(cell);

  var values;
  while (r != 4) {
    values = range.getValues();
    var r = values.filter(function(e) {return e[0]}).length;
  }
  var res = values.map(function(e, i) {return e[0] == "#N/A" || e[0] == "" ? ['=IMPORTXML(C' + (i + 2) + ', "/html/body/div[3]")'] : [""]});
  range2.setFormulas(res);
}
```

Comment: I didn't explain correctly, sorry.
I edit the first post for more informations m(_ _)m

Comment: @overer Thank you for replying. And about your new question, I would like to confirm in order to understand what you want to really do. 1. In your script, the formula is put to "D2:D5" and "E2:E5". What is each ``information`` of ``The first, to get information in D2:D5`` and ``The second, to get information in E2:E5`` meaning? 2. About ``if the result is nothing (#N/A) in D2:D5``, please provide the detail information. 3. Can you provide the detail information about ``it check everything so it's not good.``?

Comment: @overer 4. Can you provide a sample spreadsheet including the input and output you want? By this, it will help to understand. I'm sorry for my poor skill. But I would like to resolve your issue. Can you cooperate to resolve your issue?

Comment: I check 4 differents addresses.
- The websites are dynamic, so the informations are not in the same place everytime.
- I saw there is only two paterns, so sometime the first xpath is wrong. It's for that I check with two differents xpath.

Comment: - Now, my script check the First and the Second in the same time. It will be better to check the First, keep only the value, and after that check the Second.

Comment: @overer Thank you for replying I understand as follows. 1. Cells of "D2:E5" have already been put the formulas with 2 patterns. 2. You want to confirm whether each cell of "D2:E5" has a value (value or formula?), respectively. 3. I cannot understand what you want to do after you confirmed the cells.

Comment: @overer And I have questions. About "Now, my script check the First and the Second in the same time.", can I ask you where part it is in your script? And "the First and the Second" are "The first, to get information in D2:D5" and "The second, to get information in E2:E5 if the result is nothing (#N/A) in D2:D5", respectively?

Comment: I made an example here >> https://tof.cx/images/2018/10/03/0ea92842ea0251490ddd1f85687bbbb1.png

Comment: @overer Thank you for showing the image. By this, I could understand what you want to do. I added the modified script. Could you please confirm it? If that is not what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Sugoi :o Thank you, it works perfect! :)) I'm not sure if it's possible, but do you think, we can put a "timer".
I mean, in the future, if it's not D2:D5 but D2:D9999999, can we put a laps of xx ms: "when D2:D50 and E2:E50 is finished, execute D51:D99 and E51:E99"

Comment: @overer Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was solved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. And about your new question, I couldn't understand about the timer you want. But if you want to put the timer which is updated with such fast speed to the cell, it cannot be achieved because of the low speed for putting values.

Comment: I mean, can we use your function for the cells of D2:D51 and E2:E51. When value is get in all cells, we execute once again (like 10 minutes after) the function for next D52:D99 and E52:E99.

Comment: @overer In that case, the script can be used. At that time, please modify the range.