# Xpath remove comma in number

Tags: google-sheets

Follow the question [setValue in range if nothing in an other range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583196/setvalue-in-range-if-nothing-in-an-other-range/52583299#52583299) .

With my Xpath I get numbers with a comma:

- 1
- 10
- 100
- 1,000
- 10,000
- 100,000 etc

How can I remove this comma. I tried some options of Google Sheet like the format/number but it's not work.

Is there a magic way to remove it by the script editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this:`=IMPORTXML(C2, "/html/body/div[3]")` is returning say `10,000` then I'd expect:

```
=substitute(IMPORTXML(C2, "/html/body/div[3]"),",","")
```

to return `10000` as Text and:

```
=1*substitute(IMPORTXML(C2, "/html/body/div[3]"),",","")
```

`10000` as Number.